# ¿Cómo incluir un archivo de conexión server en php?

Tags: php, sql-server, apache2

Tengo una clase php de conexión a una base de datos sql server, *conexion.php*, y un archivo de inserción en donde incluyo el archivo de la conexión para poder insertar registros; no estoy logrando la inserción por que me sale un error que dice: "*Se pasó un parámetro no válido a sqlsrv_query*"

Este es el código de la conexión

```html
   <?php
   
class conexion {

    public function conectar($base = "") {
        $serverName = "server";
        $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "bd", "UID" => "sa", "PWD" => "123", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

        if ($conn) {

            return $conn;
        } else {
            echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";

            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    }
}

$class = new conexion ();
$class->conectar();

?>
```

En este archivo es donde hago un llamado a la clase conexion.php para hacer la inserción.

```html
<?php
   include "conexion.php";
   $class = new conexion ();
   $class->conectar();
   $sql = "INSERT INTO ORG_LOG2 (USUARIO, ACCION, INVOLUCRADO) VALUES (?,?,?)";
   $params = array("1","2","3");

   $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
   if( $stmt === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

no le estas pasando la conexion a la base de datos solo la estas llamado:

haces:

```
$class = new conexion ();
$class->conectar();
// de donde sale $conn aqui??
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
```

debes hacer:

```
$class = new conexion ();
//asignamos connectar a la variable $conn
$conn = $class->conectar();
// resto del codigo
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
```